# Attaching labels to the vertices of an Octahedron

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

How do you attach the labels `(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6)` to all 6 vertices of the Octahedron below, ensuring that the labels of the first figure corresponds to the end points of the 2nd figure, and to the third figure (not shown).

```
PolyhedronData["Octahedron"]

PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "NetGraph"]

PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonGraph"]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the coordinates of the vertex points and combine `Text` with `Show`

To extract the coordinates

```
PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "NetCoordinates"]
PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonCoordinates"]
```

And then combine it with the label

```
labels = Style[StringForm["e``", #], 16] & /@ Range[6]
Show[PolyhedronData["Octahedron"], 
 Graphics3D[Text[labels[[#]], 
 PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "VertexCoordinates"][[#]]] & /@ Range[6]]]
Show[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "NetGraph"], 
 Graphics[Text[labels[[#]], 
 PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "NetCoordinates"][[#]]] & /@ Range[6]]]
Show[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonGraph"], 
 Graphics[Text[labels[[#]], 
 PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonCoordinates"][[#]]] & /@ Range[6]]]
```

[image]

> Label positions

```
labels = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
shift = {0.1, 0.1}; (*shifting the label from vertex*)
Show[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonGraph"], 
  Graphics[Text[labels[[#]], 
   shift + PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "SkeletonCoordinates"][[#]]] & /@ Range[6]]]
```

[image]

Comment: What if the labels are "a","b","c","d","e","f"?  Also how do you provide a spacing so that the labels don't overlap on the vertices?